# Reading from a promiscuous network device

Tags: c, linux, sockets, wireless, promiscuous-mode

I want to write a real-time analysis tool for wireless traffic.

Does anyone know how to read from a promiscuous (or sniffing) device in C?

I know that you need to have root access to do it. I was wondering if anyone knows what functions are necessary to do this. Normal sockets don't seem to make sense here.

Comment: In Linux? Your post doesn't indicate the OS, but should we assume by your use of 'root' you mean linux?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Linux you use a PF_PACKET socket to read data from a raw device, such as an ethernet interface running in promiscuous mode:

```
s = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))
```

This will send copies of every packet received up to your socket. It is quite likely that you don't really want every packet, though. The kernel can perform a first level of filtering using BPF, the [Berkeley Packet Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter). BPF is essentially a stack-based virtual machine: it handles a small set of instructions such as:

```
ldh = load halfword (from packet)  
jeq = jump if equal  
ret = return with exit code
```

BPF's exit code tells the kernel whether to copy the packet to the socket or not. It is possible to write relatively small BPF programs directly, using setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, ). (WARNING: The kernel takes a struct sock_fprog, not a struct bpf_program, do not mix those up or your program will not work on some platforms).

For anything reasonably complex, you really want to use libpcap. BPF is limited in what it can do, in particular in the number of instructions it can execute per packet. [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) will take care of splitting a complex filter up into two pieces, with the kernel performing a first level of filtering and the more-capable user-space code dropping the packets it didn't actually want to see.

libpcap also abstracts the kernel interface out of your application code. Linux and BSD use similar APIs, but Solaris requires DLPI and Windows uses something else.

Comment: Actually, no, libpcap won't split the filter into two pieces.  But, yes, libpcap is what you want to use - it knows how to put an interface into promiscuous mode on different platforms (just using `ETH_P_ALL` isn't sufficient on Linux, for example; that's "SAP promiscuous", in that you get all packets regardless of protocol type, but it's not "physically promiscuous", in that the adapter won't deliver to the host unicast packets not being sent to the host).

Answer (score 8):

I once had to listen on raw ethernet frames and ended up creating a wrapper for this. By calling the function with the device name, ex `eth0` I got a socket in return that was in promiscuous mode. 
What you need to do is to create a raw socket and then put it into promiscuous mode. Here is how I did it.

```
int raw_init (const char *device)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int raw_socket;

    memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (struct ifreq));

    /* Open A Raw Socket */
    if ((raw_socket = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 1)
    {
        printf ("ERROR: Could not open socket, Got #?\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    /* Set the device to use */
    strcpy (ifr.ifr_name, device);

    /* Get the current flags that the device might have */
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
    {
        perror ("Error: Could not retrive the flags from the device.\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    /* Set the old flags plus the IFF_PROMISC flag */
    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
    {
        perror ("Error: Could not set flag IFF_PROMISC");
        exit (1);
    }
    printf ("Entering promiscuous mode\n");

    /* Configure the device */

    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0)
    {
        perror ("Error: Error getting the device index.\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    return raw_socket;
}
```

Then when you have your socket you can just use select to handle packets as they arrive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the pcap library (see http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) which is also used by tcpdump and Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use something like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

It is open source, so at least you could learn a few things from it if you don't want to just use it.

Comment: I'm not sure if WireShark can capture the full wireless packet. I think its configured for regular MAC not wireless MAC. I need to be able to look at traffic from multiple essids.

Comment: Again, I would start by looking through the wireshark source code.

Comment: WireShark does not work with wireless cards on Windows (full stop).

Answer (score 0):

WireShark on linux has the capability to capture the PLCP (physical layer convergence protocol) header information.