# Layer 2 bridge using boost raw sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I need to build a bridge between two networks.
The layer 2 data in the network 1 must be copy in the network 2 (sending it via a UDP radio link).
I will try to:

- Read layer 2 using a boost raw socket.
- Send it using a UDP connection.
- Receive it using a UDP connection.
- Write the "layer 2 data" using a boost raw socket.

It's possible to do it using boost raw sockets? Anyone have some example code? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What have you written so far? What is giving you problems?

Comment: There are various tools and applications available that can tunnel layer 2 traffic over UDP. Would these not be more suitable?

Comment: I create a raw socket and then put it into promiscuous mode; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114804/reading-from-a-promiscuous-network-device.

I use it to read the received data of a ethernet interface. The client send me layer 2 data using this interface.

I send it using UDP over a radio data link.

I receive it, unpacket and send the data using other raw socket. The client receive the layer 2 data he send via the first socket.

It is correct? Can I transpor layer 2 data in this way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: raw_socket = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))