# Raw socket bound to device not receiving all packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, raw-sockets

I have a raw socket set up bound to a device that is already in promiscuous mode:

```
int sock = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sock == -1)
{
   return -1;
}

struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ);
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
{
    close(sock);
    return -2;
}

while(1) {
  packet_size = recvfrom(sock , buffer , 65536 , 0 , NULL, NULL);
  // packet processing...
}
```

And my issue is that I am only receiving packets on my socket with IP destination matching the IP of the device (eth0) I am bound to. How can I receive all the TCP packets that the device is receiving? I can see all the TCP packets on the device in Wireshark, but the only packets that I see in my raw socket are those addressed to the device IP.

Comment: this code block: `if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
{
    close(sock);
    return -2;
}`  needs to be removed from your code as the `ifr` struct is not yet initialized

Comment: @user3629249 updated code block, apologies that was just a mistake when copying over a simplified version of the code

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the packet mask also? Seet this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177708/raw-socket-promiscuous-mode-not-sniffing-what-i-write and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114804/reading-from-a-promiscuous-network-device

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks, I've added a packet mask for the specific interface I'm interested in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of receiving packets directed only to IP of your device is that you are using `PF_INET` raw socket. When `PF_INET` raw socket is used - `skb` faces different sanity checks when goes across the stack (see below).

F.e. :

```
int ip_rcv(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev, struct packet_type *pt, struct net_device *orig_dev)
{
    /*...*/

    /* When the interface is in promisc. mode, drop all the crap
     * that it receives, do not try to analyse it.
     */
    if (skb->pkt_type == PACKET_OTHERHOST)
        goto drop;
```

So the call trace is something like: `__netif_receive_skb_core()`->`ip_rcv()`->...->`ip_local_deliver()`->...->`raw_local_deliver()`->`raw_rcv()`->...->`tcp_rcv()` (you can check trace through the [*`trace-cmd`*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trace-cmd)).

But tcpdump/Wireshark obtains packets around `__netif_receive_skb_core()`, i.e. before some sanity checks. Hence is discrepancy that confused you.

Therefore if you want `skb`'s to bypass a large part of Linux kernel network stack - you should use [`PF_PACKET`](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/7/packet) raw sockets.

[Useful link](http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html)

Comment: PACKET_MMAP is the better mechanism to capture both incoming and outgoing packets if they are transferred with an high speed.  https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt